# Node.js module cannot be required

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

I have written a Node.js server on the Raspberry pi, and have successfully previously used several modules in it.

However, in the most recent version, which requires the package serialport, I have received the following error message:

```
 /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:85
  throw err
        ^
Error: Could not load the bindings file. Tried:
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/build/Debug/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/out/Debug/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/Debug/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/out/Release/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/Release/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/build/default/serialport.node
 -> /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/compiled/0.6/linux/arm/serialport.node
    at bindings (/home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:82:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:7:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/hub/server.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
```

I have tried searching for this error, including on stackoverflow, but the few solutions that I found did not fix the problem.

UPDATE:

For reasons I cannot discern, I'm now getting a different error. I don't remember changing anything.

```
/home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:77
        throw e
              ^
Error: Unable to load shared library     /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node
```

I've doublechecked, and I'm pretty sure that serialport is installed in the right directory

Comment: Do any of the paths that node.js tried point to an existing file? If not, what is the path of your compiled node.js module?

Comment: Did you had any errors during the 'npm install' phase? The requirements for the Raspberry pie seems to be specific.

Comment: @Sonata just checked, /home/pi/hub/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node
seems to point to an existing file. Weird that it can't find it

Comment: @AurélienThieriot didn't seem to be any errors, no

Comment: Maybe the compiled module does not match your node.js? Could you include the output of `setenv` of node.js? And the commandline for compiling your module?

Comment: Still looks like serialport is not compiled to the right target architecture. Which package are you installing that has serialport as a dependency?

Comment: @Sonata using xbee-api, for which serial port is required I believe

Comment: When using `npm install xbee-api` the package `serialport` is compiled, right? Are there any error messages? You could try starting with `node debug yourapp.js` to see if this gives you any more information.

Comment: @Sonata, finally got serialport working by installing an earlier version. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this will work if you install an earlier version of serialport:

```
npm install serialport@0.7.3
```

Guess the later versions weren't compatible with my version of nodejs